# Why does GNU Parallel extensions seems to make algorithms go slower?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, g++, stl-algorithm

I wanted to follow this guide : 
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt12ch31s03.html

Here is some example code :

```
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int> in(1000);
    vector<double> out(1000);
    iota(in.begin(), in.end(), 1);

    auto t = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
        accumulate(in.begin(), in.end(), 0);

    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t).count()  << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have the following results :

```
~:$ g++ test.cpp -std=c++11
~:$ ./a.out 
900
~:$ g++ test.cpp -D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL -std=c++11 -fopenmp -march=native 
~:$ ./a.out 
1026
```

When doing multiple runs, these two stays at about the same time.
I have also tried with other algorithms, like sort, generate, find, transform...
I have an i7, with hyperthreading enabled (4 logical cores).
I run g++-4.8.1

Thanks

Comment: Remember that there is an overhead when creating threads, and for the OS to switch between them. For small loops like yours, that overhead is probably to large, you should try with larger datasets (i.e. looping more).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to try something a little more heavy. All your doing is adding `int`s together. The overhead of creating the threads, etc. will be greater. Try replacing `int` with `std::string` and running the following code and compare the output:

```
int main()
{
    vector<string> in(100000);

    auto t = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    accumulate(in.begin(), in.end(), string(), [](string s1, string s2){ return s1 += s2 + "a" + "b";});
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t).count()  << endl;
}
```

Comment: As a side note, I get those figures if someone is interested by the amount of win offered by g++ : 

* without parallel extensions: 530 ms (average)
* without parallel and with O3 : 500 ms
* with parallel : 95 ms
* with parallel and O3 : 85 ms